# Targeting same action method in other controllers while generating an outgoing URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Let's say I have only this route:

```
routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        });
```

We can see that our startup page will be `Home/Index`.

And let's say I have created an anchor element using this code in the view:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("This targets another controller","Index", "Admin")
```

When I render the view, you will see the following HTML generated:

```
<a href="/Admin">This targets another controller</a>
```

Our request for a URL that targets the `Index` action method on the `Admin` controller has been expressed as `/Admin` by the `ActionLink` method. The routing system is pretty clever and it knows that the route defined in the application will use the `Index` action method by default, allowing it to omit unneeded segments.

**And the question is:**

***If I change the route as:***

```
routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}",
        new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional,
            name = UrlParameter.Optional
        });
```

***or*** **as:**

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{*catchall}",
         new 
         { 
            controller = "Home", 
            action = "Index", 
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
         });
```

Then, the following HTML will be generated:

```
<a href="/Admin/Index">This targets another controller</a>
```

Could you explain me why?

Comment: I would think that route would be problematic. Having two pattern segments be optional, it would be indeterminate whether `/Admin/Index/4` means id=4, or name=4, unless you had `/Admin/Index//4`, which isnt valid either.

Comment: Are you using areas in your project?

Comment: Only the last parameter can be optional.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the comment. But, there is not any official source which stated that restriction about Optional Parameters. And, why then Compiler has not warned me?

Comment: @NightOwl888 Not, I am not using. In fact, I have started to read book about Asp.Net MVC recently. So, I haven't any project on MVC now. 
I have tried this while reading my book and got the unexpected result.

Comment: @Tejs But, why this does prevent framework to be pretty clever again and create the same Url which it has created before.

Comment: Its not a compiler error, Its just that the routing engine cant resolve the routes ( as @Tejs has indicated). If your were to change `id = UrlParameter.Optional,` to (say) `id=1`, then you would get `<a href="/Admin">` instead of `<a href="/Admin/Index">`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I test `/Admin/Index/4` with two optional parameters in that route and it worked fine. So, to tell the truth I can't totally agree with your comments. Because, these coudn't explain me what is going under the hood and why the result is different for that two routes.

Comment: Yes it works, but you wanted to know why it displayed `/Admin/Index` and not just `/Admin` and that is what I have explained to you. If you have only the last parameter as optional you will get `/Admin`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok, I updated the question with another route which includes only one Optional Parameter. But, it produces the same result. Could you please explain or add as an asnwer the overall result?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev, You haven't really change anything. The `{id}` parameter is not the last one and `{*catchall}` is really a sort of optional parameter anyway. Not sure what else I can add that's not already been said - the helper will generate what is necessary so there can be no ambiguity/indetermancy

Comment: @StephenMuecke I can also figure out the reasons which can be behind this result. But, The point which I don't understand is why this does prevent framework to be pretty clever again and create the same Url which it has created before? The reason of this question was this. Unfortunately, I didn't understand this behaviour of framework after all these comments. May be I need to look at the source code of MVC framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both:

```
routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional,
        name = UrlParameter.Optional
    });
```

and:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{*catchall}",
     new 
     { 
        controller = "Home", 
        action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
     });
```

are invalid route definitions because only the last segment of a route can be optional. Otherwise the routing engine cannot disambiguate your routes.

Now back to your original question as why for those routes the framework doesn't infer the `/Index` part. This is because the framework, when evaluating your route pattern it sees this:

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}
```

See that `{id}` portion of your route? When it analyzes this pattern it knows in advance that the `{action}` part is followed by a **non optional** segment (`{id}` in your case) which you must **always** be present. And since it knows that it, is pretty obvious that it cannot be clever and omit the `/Index` part and it doesn't even try to. On the other hand you can specify a default value for your **last** segment and it will be omitted when generating routes with this value.

Comment: Now, this makes a sense. *When it analyzes this pattern it knows in advance that the {action} part is followed by a non optional parameter id which you must specify.* Thanks very much for the answer. 
But also, one weird thing is that I can't find any official source which stated that restriction about Optional Parameters.